# Can I tell what wifi strength I have when creating matches?

Tags: dragon-ball-fighterz

When I get a prompt to fight other people online, I can see their wifi signal and decide if it's too weak to bother playing with. Can I see what my wifi strength is being broadcasted as when I propose a match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "wifi signal" is latency between the players and you. This game (as do most fighting games) uses peer to peer connection, which means your latency is always going to be 0 for yourself and the same for your opponent as your opponents latency is for you.